# cin.getline Not working with switch statement

Tags: c++, string

Here is my piece of code from my program, cin.getline is not working with switch statement but without switch statement it works, when I use it with switch statement it just skips the input So in my code I have commented cin.getline and replaced it with cin>>userData;

Please tell me what is the problem When I use it with switch statement.

```
switch(option)
{

case 1:
    cout<<"Enter string "<<endl;
    //cin.getline(userData, 100);
    cin.getline(userData,100);
```

Comment: You should show a compiled example of the problem. The code you showed has no sense relative to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that there is an `\n` in your input stream, from previous code that you unfortunately don't show in the question, and you need to flush it for `cin.getline()` to work.

The accepted wisdom is to use `ignore`:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
cin.getline(userData,100);
```

Comment: I have already used using namespace std please tell me cin.ignore line again

Comment: Here I updated the answer and removed std. But know thus - it is much better to be explicit with the std namespace. Saves much ADL pain at times.

Answer (score 1):

Your code [works](https://ideone.com/PmU8ux)

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    char userData[100];
    auto option = 1;
    switch(option) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Enter string" << std::endl;
            std::cin.getline(userData, 100);
    }

    std::cout << userData;

    return 0;
}
```

There must be something you're not showing.

Comment: No, it is **your** code that works :) Try adding `cout << "Give me a number" << endl; cin >> i;` before `cin.getline()` to have an `\n` hanging around in the buffer from pressing Enter.

Comment: There is no `cout << "Give me a num" << endl; cin >> i;` in OP's code.

Comment: Nor there is `auto option = 1;` in OP's code. I was trying to make the point that you cannot prove that OPs code work "by extension".

Comment: OP's code doesn't compile by itself at all. The fragment he has shown works as intended if there is no other code that breaks it, as proved by my example. Hence statement "There must be something you're not showing." OP should present a complete (minimal) example that produces the error. His current code is not such an example.